# How to parse JSON data to SCSS?

Tags: json, webpack, sass

I our project we are suppose to parse the data from json to scss. Below is the test code.

```
`@import "variables.json";

 .textprimaryblue {
  color: $color;
}`
```

I have installed sass and using the following command to convert the scss to css

```
node_modules\.bin\sass styletest.scss test.css
```

but when i run the command i see the following error `Error: Can't find styletest to import`

We cannot use `gem install sass-json-vars` due to some restrictions.

Would like to know if there is any other way to parse the data from json to scss.  We are using webpack module bundler

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you import a json?

Comment: We should be able to use the various properties which are defined in the JSON when it is imported in SCSS.

Comment: https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer/blob/master/README.md ?